# Cannot set the height of a ListView as a Gallery Item to fill_parent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Gallery control that displays a ListView as its adapter view.

my problem is that each gallery item (ListView) appears small though I have set the height of the ListView and the Gallery itself to **fill_parent**.

is there a way to make the ListView take all the available vertical space available for the Gallery ?

Thanks

Comment: Where do your get your pics from for your adapter view? A database?

Comment: no, they are not pics, they are some text in a custom adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it, I had to set the Layout Paramters of the gallery item programmatically in my adapter class

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
            convertView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            holder=new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.setAdapter(mItems.get(i));
        return convertView;
    }
```